# In App purchase user press cancel receive SKErrorDomain Code=2

Tags: objective-c, in-app-subscription

i've developed an app with in app purchase integrated, When performing in app purchase i just press cancel halfway, it return SKErrorDomain Code=2 is there any document from apple regarding this?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/in-app-purchase/

Answer (score 0):

It is [SKErrorPaymentCancelled](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skerrorcode/skerrorpaymentcancelled?language=objc) from StoreKit/SKError.h.

Check these links:

- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skerrorcode?language=objc
- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/handling_errors?language=objc